# Using Java delimiters to match any one character

Tags: java, character, delimiter

I have done a search but have not been able to find an example that explained so I understood or that pertained to my exact question. I am trying to write a program that cancels out the letters A and B and reads the numbers inbetween, such as A38484B3838. I tried using

```
    scanner.useDelimiter("[AB]");
```

but it doesnt work. It throws invalid input (I'm reading `scanner.nextInt()`) after it. can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the code, you're trying to read with?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "A38484B3838";
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("[AB]");
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
  }
}
```

produces

```
38484
3838
```

It seems like the output you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **regular expressions**. It could really facilitate your work.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "A38484B3838";
    String regex = "(\\d+)";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(m.group()));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

**Output** of the program above:

> [38484, 3838]